# Drush doesn't work in remote server, using PuTTY. (Ruby, Sass, Compass i.e. work)

Tags: drupal, putty, drush

Tried to log into a remote server via PuTTY client. Commands like ruby, sass and compass work, but not drush.

```
user@example.com [~]# drush
-bash: /home/user/.composer/vendor/bin/drush: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Drush is not installed Run:

```
composer install
```

See http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

If composer is not installed check https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: Well, I asked my senior developer, and he said that drush is installed globally for all projects but is not working for all users. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: If composer is working have you gone into the directory with the composer.json file and run composer install?this [link](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/drush-drupal)  has some helpful notes about instaling drush globally